# QT Creator release build

Tags: c++, shared-library, qt-creator, opencv, qt5

So I was just wondering about this and I couldn't find a sure answer online and I need to be sure. I have some libraries in my project like OpenCV. And the question is: after I build the release version of my project, will it run on Ubuntu computers that don't have qt or OpenCV libraries installed?

I am new to Ubuntu and haven't worked on Linux before.

Comment: Hmm... Might be easier to find an answer on http://www.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your question directly but can provide you with a method of checking.  When I write a program for deployment I create various virtual machines with minimum installations to see how it behaves in those environments.

You can create a [VirtualBox](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) machine without the qt or OpenCV libraries to see how your project behaves, then explore methods to provide what is needed in your distribution package to work on various machines.

Comment: Thank you,
This will actually help me :) because i didn't think of it..

Many thanks again!

Comment: @KarloSantini After testing the suggestion, if it works, consider hitting the up arrow to indicate it has merit or the check mark if it resolves your issue.  Also, the least that it will do is help you to have more definition for new followup questions such as which libraries and the process of including them with your package distributions.